# Unable to understand output of Python Negative List Slice

Tags: python, list

UPDATE: I got code from sololearn.com (freemium site to teach Python). And I ran code on my own Python 3.

I don't understand this output

```
sqs = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
print(sqs[7:5:-1])
[49, 36]
```

Is the interpreter skipping 0th element, i.e. 0 and reading list as `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]`, and then printing the 7th element, i.e `49`?

How does it then print `36`? Does it go forward and read `[64,81]`, then read backwards `[64,49,36]`, hence printing 5th element, i.e. `36`?

If this is correct, then explain following output

```
>>> print(sqs[7:4:-1])
[49, 36, 25]
```

I can understand that python skips the 0th element, counts till 7 and prints `49`. But now I specified a gap of 4. So shouldn't the interpreter read `[64,81]`, then go in reverse, i.e. `[64,49]`, and print `49`? And how did it print `25`?

Comment: The notation means start at the seventh index `7`, until the fifth (not including it) `5` and decrease 1 each time (step `-1`).

Comment: sqs[7:4:-1] means it starts with the 7th element and read backward with -1, e.g. reads 6th, 5th, and then stops reading because it's now on the 4th element.

Comment: 49 is at index 7, 36 is at index 6. Remember, the first index is 0, not 1.

Comment: @pault I saw the duplicate question, it did not help me, hence this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slice `[i:j:k]` says take the elements starting at index i, stepping by k, until j is reached. So [7,4,-1] get indices 7, 6, and 5. See [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations).

Comment: I didn't see it that way. Because we are going backwards it is 7, 6, 5 (but the 5th element is not printed, it is merely a border). If I specified `print(sqs[7:3:-1])`, it would print 7th, 6th, 5th, 4th elements.

Answer (score 2):

See the defination for `range()` method in Python docs.

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

Here, start specifies the value from where it will start, stop specifies the value before which it has to stop i.e stop-1. step denotes the jump.
Now, if the parameters are something like `range(2,5,1)`, then it will start from 2, then make a jump of 1 i.e add 1 to 2. Now, again it will add 1 to 3, and it becomes 4. Now, 4 is equal to 5-1. Hence it stops.

List slicing is something similar. Now, you have something like this:

```
sqs[7:5:-1]
```

This is similar to range but here start is 7, stop is 5 and step size is -1. Hence it generates a descending order list. Now the values it generates are :

```
[7, 6]
```

5 is not counted because, stop =5 and we have to consider only upto stop-1, i.e `5-(-1) = 6`.
This is how it works.

Comment: I will describe slicing after explaining range method. It will be much easier to understand this way.

Comment: FWIW although the answer started with an unrelated explanation, I think it was a good illustration using `range()` to help understand.  Would probably be better if you linked the slice documentation to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, it is really helpful to make clear references using comparisions and analogy.